# How to model belongs_to through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the three models Category,ItemType and Item.In plain english i can put my requirement as:A Category can have zero or more itemtypes.A ItemType must belong to only a single category and can have zero or more items.An Item belongs to an itemtype and a category thru the itemtype.i've associated them as below:

```
 class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :item_types
   has_many :items ,:through => item_types, :source => category
 end  
 class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :items
 end
 class Item < ActiveRecord ::Base
   belongs_to :item_type
 end
```

Now How can i associate an item with a category.One of my views need to show all the items of a category.
When i query it as

```
   Category.joins(:item_types,:items).where("categories.id=?",1)
```

i get the below sql

```
  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "item_types" ON "item_t
  ypes"."category_id" = "categories"."id" INNER JOIN "item_types"   
  "item_types_categories_join" ON "item_types_categories_join"."category_id" =
  "categories"."id" INNER JOIN "categories" "items_categor
  ies" ON "items_categories"."id" = "item_types_categories_join"."category_id" WHERE
  (categories.id=1)
```

Can anyone help me out here.How to get the below sql

```
 select * from categories 
      inner join item_type on categories.id=item_types.category_id
      inner join items on item_types.id=items.item_type_id
 where categories.id =1
```

Comment: Typo? ":through => subcategories" doesnt make sense otherwise.

Comment: And the same goes for "joins(:business_types,:businesses)"

Comment: @Atastor i've tried change the original names..now i've made sure its consistent everywhere

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, the association declaration is incomplete. You may need to add `belongs_to :category` in ItemType & Item model. For example:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :item_types
   has_many :items ,:through => item_types
 end  
 class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :items
   belongs_to :category
 end
 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :item_type
   belongs_to :category
 end
```

now an instance of category should be able to list all the items. As you wanted to list all items of a category, you should get it by:

```
cat = Category.find_by_id(ID_GOES_HERE)
cat.items
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
#this will load your item_types and items earlier with less query.
Category.find(1, :include => [:item_types, :items])
```

Also your models needs following changes

```
 class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
 ... ...
 +    belongs_to :category
 end

 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 ... ...
 +    belongs_to :category
 end
```

Here is a related link - [Rails Active Record: find in conjunction with :order and :group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129792/rails-active-record-find-in-conjunction-with-order-and-group). You might get more details here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I would rely on rails magic here. Can you try

```
Category.includes([:item_types,:items]).where(['items.item_type_id = ?',categories.item_type.id]).where(<...your conditions...>)
```

Sorry for not having time to check it myself before posting :-(